# phaseCorrelate function in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

The phaseCorrelate seems to be an undocumented function of the OpenCV Python wrapper. The doc of the C++ function is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=phasecorrelate#Point2d%20phaseCorrelate%28InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20InputArray%20window%29).

When I call the function from Python I get the following error:

```
cv2.error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\phasecorr.cpp:495: error: (-215)    src1.type() == CV_32FC1 || src1.type() == CV_64FC1
```

Every OpenCV 2 function uses numpy arrays, I suspect that this function has been left from the older wrapper. Maybe I need to convert the numpy arrays to CvMats before calling the function? How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to convert it into cvMat.

The error says your input should be of `float32` or `float64` with single channel.

So convert the images accordingly.

And both the images should be of same size. Then apply phaseCorrelate function, as follows:

```
>>> src1 = cv2.imread('sudoku.jpg',0)   # load first image in grayscale
>>> src2 = cv2.imread('su1.png',0)      # load second image in grayscale
>>> src1 = np.float32(src1)             # convert first into float32
>>> src2 = np.float32(src2)             # convert second into float32  
>>> ret = cv2.phaseCorrelate(src1,src2) # now calculate the phase correlation
>>> ret
(-0.024777238426224812, 0.0011736626157130559)
```

(Both my images are same, except change in brightness.)

Regarding documentation, you can post a bug report at `code.opencv.org`.

Comment: I almost forgot to mention that I love your blog, extremely helpful.

Comment: Can I calculate the angle of difference of the two pictures using the phasecorrelate() results?

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the [docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html#numpy-and-opencv) you can convert a `numpy` array into a `CvMat` as follows:

```
>>> import cv, numpy
>>> a = numpy.ones((480, 640))
>>> mat = cv.fromarray(a)
>>> print mat.rows
480
>>> print mat.cols
640
```